# Read SpecFlow parameters from an external xml

Tags: c#, specflow, acceptance-testing

I have an object through I can access to variables read from an external file, and i want to implement it into my specflow tests.

where can I initialize my object to have it visible from ALL test steps?

edit:
i tried to initialize my object in the first step, which is the first step fo ALL my tests, but i can't access my object from nowhere else

Comment: can someone please explain all those downvotes?

Comment: Please, read nice article from: whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0):

You could initialise the object in your Given step(s) and store it as a private variable, so it's accessible on all steps

Comment: steps are just methods, so they have the scope a method usually has. you could declare it as static in a seperate class and have it accessible from any of the steps in any of your test classes.

Comment: ok, but the constructor of my class reads an xml file... if the class is static, how can it be initialized?

Comment: you can have a static helper class which instantiates your xml reader, then access it through the static class in all steps. this isnt really a specflow problem, its kind of just program design. theres not enough info for me to give you an exact answer.